DSolve cannot solve this system of ODEs with symbolic coefficients
I want to obtain a solution from the following system of ODEs with symbolic coefficients, but the code keeps running without providing any results. I am not sure if there is an error somewhere, or if DSolve is unable to solve such systems.
ClearAll["Global`*"];

eqns = {Derivative[1][y][x] == (x - a z[x])/(-y[x] + b z[x]),
    Derivative[1][z][x] == (b x - a y[x])/(y[x] - b z[x])};

solutions = DSolve[eqns, {y[x], z[x]}, x]

eqns2 = solutions /. Rule[a_, b_] :> a == b

FirstInt1 = Solve[eqns2[[1]], {C[1], C[2]}] /. Rule[a_, b_] :> a == b

The solution given in the textbook is as follows:
$ ax+by+z=c_1, \quad x^2+y^2+z^2=c_2 $

you have coupled first order ode's which are non-linear. These are very hard for computers to solve. I verified your book solution is correct.  Mathematica can't solve these. Maple gives solution but in terms of unresolved integrals. You have hit the limit of what CAS can do at this time with solving pde's.

Yes, I also tried solving it with Maple, and the result was a very complicated unresolved integral.

This problem is similar to your previous one, and exactly the same method mentioned in my answer therein applies. We just need to eliminate the non-derivative terms and integrate:
integrate = Integrate[Subtract @@ #, x] &;

Eliminate[eqns, z[x]]
(* -b y'[x] - z'[x] == a *)

% // integrate
(* -a x - b y[x] - z[x] *)

Eliminate[eqns, a]
(* x + y[x] y'[x] + z[x] z'[x] == 0 *)

% // integrate
(* x^2/2 + y[x]^2/2 + z[x]^2/2 *)


It is very hard to obtain the explicit solution to the ODE. Without explicit solution, however, you can check that both $c_1$ and $c_2$ are conserved quantities:
sol = First@Solve[eqns, {y'[x], z'[x]}]


D[a x + b y[x] + z[x], x] /. sol // Simplify
(* 0 *) 

D[x^2 + y[x]^2 + z[x]^2, x] /. sol // Simplify
(* 0 *)

